# Google Compute Engine VM instance access permission

Tags: google-compute-engine

I got some issues when dealing with the Google VM instances, 
I use this command to create a instance at the beginning,

```
gcloud compute instances create <instance name> \
--scopes storage-rw,bigquery,compute-rw \
--image-family container-vm \
--image-project google-containers \
--zone us-central1-b \
--machine-type n1-standard-1
```

The instance is working well, and I can do a lot of things on the instance.

However, in the project, there are several other users, and every user in the same project can SSH access to my instance and see my work, and they have sudo permission, which means they can also change my settings, documents and so on. It is not secure.

Is there a method to set up the instance to be personal instead of public to the project? In this case, everyone in the project can have his/her own VM, and no one else can access it except himself/herself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to allow only access to particular users in a VM and not to other project SSH keys, you must block the propagation of project level keys to the instance. In that way only the specific keys defined to the instance will have access to it. The details are explained in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys?hl=en_US&_ga=1.201630165.532545591.1475676363#instance-only)

The command to deploy such an instance at the creation time would look something like this

```
gcloud compute --project "myproject" instances create "myinstance" --zone "us-central1-f" --machine-type "n1-standard-1" --network "default" --metadata "block-project-ssh-keys=true,ssh-keys=MYPUBLICKEYVLUE" --maintenance-policy "MIGRATE" --scopes default="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly" --image "/debian-cloud/debian-8-jessie-v20160923" --boot-disk-size "10" --boot-disk-type "pd-standard" --boot-disk-device-name "myinstance"
```

Now if you have defined a Project Member as Owner/Editor, the key will still get automatically transferred to the instance when he SSH using gcloud or the Developer Console.  This behaviour makes sense since the permissions at the project level allows him to even delete the VM.

If your instance is already created you must change block-project-ssh-keys metadata value to TRUE and delete any undesired keys in the VM, as explained in the same [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys?hl=en_US&_ga=1.201630165.532545591.1475676363#instance-only)

Comment: Hi, is that mean, as long as the project member is the Owner/Editor, they still can SSH access or modify my VM instance? Since every member in the project is Editor, each VM instance will be open to all users?  THX

Comment: You are right. By definition a project owner or editor can modify and configure resources as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/permissions-overview) . If the users still need access to the project, other than ¨viewer¨, you can achieve additional granularity by using [IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/)

Comment: Another approach is to exclude the other users from the project or grant ¨viewer¨ permissions. Then you can setup an SSH key for them and spin the VMs. After that you can give them the IP address and the private key in order to SSH to the respective VM. You can also choose to have only one VM and control the permissions at the [Operating System level](http://www.tecmint.com/manage-users-and-groups-in-linux/)

Comment: Thank you very much, that make more sense.